# How to read extentions with depth greater than one from custom gradle plugin?

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to create a custom extension with some dynamic name as

```
myExt {
  aNameChoosenByUser{
    firstname = 'toto'
    age       = 2
  }
  aNameChoosenByUser2{
    firstname = 'tata'
    age       = 3
  }
}
```

I use usually:

```
project.extensions.create("myExt", APluginExtension)
```

but here I do not know when I create the plugin "aNameChoosenByUser", "aNameChoosenByUser2" . I would like let user to define it. And After iterate as it was a `HashMap<String,APluginExtension>` .

I do not want to define "aNameChoosenByUser" into my plugin.

It is possible to do it with groovy/gradle ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to create is a [`NamedDomainObjectContainer`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html) which can be done by calling `Project.container()` and passing a type. In this case, rather than defining a type for you extension, you'll want to define a type for the model object of the container.

```
project.extensions.create('myExt', project.container(User.class))

public class User {
    String firstname;
    String age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. and once this done to iterate over all Users should I use project.extensions.each{ ... } ?

Comment: You would simply refer to your extension by name, which would return the collection, allowing you to do `project.myExt.each {...}`. Better yet, `NamedDomainObjectContainer` is a type of "live" collection so you can do `project.myExt.all {...}` which has the benefit of executing on every item in the collection now and in the future. This allows you to avoid having to do things like `project.afterEvaluate {...}` in your plugins.